How do I exclude certain elements from a flexbox in css without wrapping the element in a new div?
I am making calculator where someone can add and remove input fields using JavaScript. I've implemented a flexbox layout for the section that contains the input fields and buttons. The current CSS structure places all elements (input fields and buttons) in a column because the parent container is set to flex-direction: column;.
The problem is that this makes my buttons to be in a column as well and I want it to be horizontally aligned. I can't wrap the buttons in a div since it will interfere with my javascript.


function addClass(){
    let container = document.getElementById("input-field-1").parentNode;
    let fieldLength = container.getElementsByClassName("inputfield").length;
    let inputField = document.getElementById("input-field-1");
    let clone = inputField.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "input-field-" + (fieldLength + 1);
    let classNumber = fieldLength + 1;
    let inputs = clone.getElementsByTagName("input");
    inputs[0].placeholder = "Class "+ classNumber;
    inputs[0].value = "";
    inputs[1].value = "";
    inputs[2].value = "";
    let addButton = document.getElementById("add-btn");
    container.insertBefore(clone, addButton);
}
.semester-calc {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
<div class="semester-calc">
    <div class="inputfield" id="input-field-1">
        <input class="class-name" type="text" placeholder="Class 1">
        <input class="grade-val" type="text" placeholder="Grade">
        <input class="credit-val" type="text" placeholder="Credits">
    </div>
    <!-- Additional input fields -->
    <button id="add-btn" onclick="addClass()">Add Class</button>
    <button id="remove-btn" onclick="remove()">Remove Class</button>
    <button id="clear-btn" onclick="clearClass()">Clear Classes</button>
    <button id="calculate-gpa" onclick="calculate()">Calculate!</button>
</div>



Problem: I want the buttons to align horizontally below the input fields but the flexbox makes them align in a column. Putting it in a div seems to interfere with my javascript parent container setup so I dont want to do this. Is there a way I can align the buttons horizontally without altering my javascript or do I have to just redo my addClass function?

it should be in a div, same as how you are handling the inputs

"I can't wrap the buttons in a div since it will interfere with my javascript." - well then modify the JavaScript accordingly ...?

instead of cloning the elements, have you thought of working with <template> ? that way you can separate your logic and your structure and you can wrap your buttons any way you like (you can also do that without template, but it might make it even cleaner in the end)

did you try to embed the button controls inside their own div container and then change the js so that when using insertBefore you'll pass such div instead of the add button. Of course there are better ways to achieve that goal.. but yet yours still would work once you applied my suggestion above

You can set the buttons to be inline elements:
.semester-calc:nth-child(-n + 3){
    display: inline;
}

Is kind of a hack, but it will work like you expect:


function addClass(){
    let container = document.getElementById("input-field-1").parentNode;
    let fieldLength = container.getElementsByClassName("inputfield").length;
    let inputField = document.getElementById("input-field-1");
    let clone = inputField.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "input-field-" + (fieldLength + 1);
    let classNumber = fieldLength + 1;
    let inputs = clone.getElementsByTagName("input");
    inputs[0].placeholder = "Class "+ classNumber;
    inputs[0].value = "";
    inputs[1].value = "";
    inputs[2].value = "";
    let addButton = document.getElementById("add-btn");
    container.insertBefore(clone, addButton);
}
.semester-calc {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.semester-calc:nth-child(-n + 3){
    display: inline;
}
<div class="semester-calc">
    <div class="inputfield" id="input-field-1">
        <input class="class-name" type="text" placeholder="Class 1">
        <input class="grade-val" type="text" placeholder="Grade">
        <input class="credit-val" type="text" placeholder="Credits">
    </div>
    <!-- Additional input fields -->
    <button id="add-btn" onclick="addClass()">Add Class</button>
    <button id="remove-btn" onclick="remove()">Remove Class</button>
    <button id="clear-btn" onclick="clearClass()">Clear Classes</button>
    <button id="calculate-gpa" onclick="calculate()">Calculate!</button>
</div>



